# UICollectionView cell. trying to animate subviews

Tags: swift, uicollectionviewcell

trying to animate a subview inside a collection view cell but am only getting an abrupt change between states.

```
...

    func animate (){
    if self.signOut.hidden == false{
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2) {
            self.signOut.hidden = true
        }
    }else{
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2) {
            self.signOut.hidden = false
        }
    }

...
```

any tips much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to decrease the alpha inside an animation block for the view to disappear smoothly

```
      UIView.animateWithDuration(0.33, delay: 0.0, options: [.CurveEaseInOut], animations: {
            self.signOut.alpha = 0.0
        }) { finished in
            self.signOut.hidden = true
        }
```